# cluster the list of binary string based on hamming distance in python

Tags: python, database, cluster-computing, data-mining, hierarchical-clustering

Given a list of binary strings which represents fuzzy hashes, is there any way that the strings(hexa or binary or long) can be clustered together based on hamming distance? Any help or suggestion is greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: it could be, but you will have a lot of clusters, since that any new unique distance will be considered as a new cluster .. is that what you want?

Comment: yes, the solution can have  any number of clusters based on its unique distance between the strings.

Comment: check these questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27739872/optimal-way-to-cluster-set-of-strings-with-hamming-distance ,   https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/133260/clustering-nodes-with-hamming-distance-3