# SSE4a with ctypes in python? (gcc __builtin_popcount)

Tags: python, gcc, ctypes, sse

Here is the sample code

[Efficiently find binary strings with low Hamming distance in large set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6389841/efficiently-find-binary-strings-with-low-hamming-distance-in-large-set/6390606#6390606)

```
static inline int distance(unsigned x, unsigned y)
{
   return __builtin_popcount(x^y);
}
```

Is it possible to rewrite the above gcc code in python using ctypes
(preferably Win/*nix compatible)?

TIA!

Comment: `__builtin_*` are GCC built-in, not C functions, so I would not expect `ctypes` to be able to call them.

Answer (score 3):

The [gmpy](http://code.google.com/p/gmpy/) library can calculate the Hamming distance between two integers. Even though it may be more general than you require, it will be faster than calling code via ctypes.

Disclaimer: I maintain gmpy.