# How do I find the least hamming distance matrix from a set of matrices for a given matrix?

Tags: algorithm, matrix, data-structures, hamming-distance, binary-matrix

I have a very large set of 400x400 binary matrices **M**. For a given binary matrix **A**, how do I find the matrix **B** within the set **M** such that it has the least hamming distance from **A**?

Comment: Compute all the hamming distances d(A, B), and take the B for which it's minimal?

Comment: oops, forgot to include infinitely large set of binary matrices! edited it

Comment: What size are your matrices? There are only `2^(n.m)` binary matriecs of size n x m .

Comment: they are 400x400

Comment: Is there any structure, and how large is "very large"? If there is no structure, you have to at least read all the matrices in M. If it's really "very large" this will be very long...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably a duplicate of this question:

[Efficiently find binary strings with low Hamming distance in large set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6389841/efficiently-find-binary-strings-with-low-hamming-distance-in-large-set)

The fact that your string represents a matrix does not change anything to the hamming distance.

For something fancier, you can also look at this recent paper:

https://www.cas.mcmaster.ca/ashtiani/papers/online-nearest-neighbor.pdf